# sinon not properly restoring stubbed prototype method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon

It appears that sinon may not be restoring a stubbed prototype properly.  Before I report it as a bug, can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

#### this fails:

The following code appears to properly stub net.Socket.prototype.connect, but does not properly restore it: subsequent tests -- unrelated to this code, but dependent on net.Socket -- start to fail:

```
it('passes host and port to the net.Socket().connect()', sinon.test(function() {
  var stub = sinon.stub(net.Socket.prototype, 'connect');
  var host = '11.22.33.44';
  var port = 1234;
  var il = new InstrumentLink(host, port);
  expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith(host, port);
}));
```

Note that I'm using the 'wrapped function' `sinon.test(function() ...)` which is supposed to create and restore a sandbox.

#### this works:

On the other hand, the following code properly restores the stub and the rest of my test suite continues to run:

```
var stub;
beforeEach(function() {
  stub = sinon.stub(net.Socket.prototype, 'connect');
});
afterEach(function() {
  stub.restore();
});

it('passes host and port to the net.Socket().connect()', function() {
  stub = sinon.stub(net.Socket.prototype, 'connect');
  var host = '11.22.33.44';
  var port = 1234;
  var il = new InstrumentLink(host, port);
  expect(stub).to.have.been.calledWith(host, port);
});
```

#### the question:

Is this a bug or a cockpit error on my part?  I prefer the wrapped function approach rather than the explicit `beforeEach` and `afterEach`, so it would be nice to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sinon.js documentation (http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sandbox) states:

> so if you don’t want to manually restore(), you have to use this.spy() instead of sinon.spy() (and stub, mock).

This might help with your issue.

Apart from that, allow me to mention that I usually use a sinon sandbox like this:

```
var sinon = require('sinon').sandbox.create();
```

This allows me to do a general

```
  afterEach(function () {
    sinon.restore();
  });
```

without being required to maintain a reference to all my stubs and restoring them individually.

Comment: To be fair, the answer that @robertklep gave was first and it solved my problem.  But your answer is correct and much more helpful.

Comment: Thank you! To be honest, I read his answer, did not understand it, solved the problem by myself, wrote the answer, and only then I realized that he had said the same...